# Amazon Mechanical Turk qualification test required

Tags: node.js, rest, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am trying to create qualification mandatory for AMT HIT. But after posting this data HIT shows qualification required is none. Is that anything wrong with this data I am posting? There is no documentation for qualification test.

Is this feature really works using web service api?

```
Title=Rate%20an%20image&Description=Determine%20if%20an%20image%20is%20inappropriate%20for%20children%20or%20in%20the%20workplace.&Reward.1.Amount=0.01&Reward.1.CurrencyCode=USD&&AssignmentDurationInSeconds=180&Keywords=image%20inappropriate&qualificationRequirement.1.QualificationTypeId=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&qualificationRequirement.1.Comparator=EqualTo&qualificationRequirement.1.IntegerValue=10&qualificationRequirement.1.RequiredToPreview=true&AWSAccessKeyId=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&Timestamp=2012-11-29T07%3A04%3A15.867Z&Signature=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&Service=AWSMechanicalTurkRequester&Operation=RegisterHITType&Version=2008-08-02
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct data stream.

Title=Rate%20an%20image&Description=Determine%20if%20an%20image%20is%20inappropriate%20for%20children%20or%20in%20the%20workplace.&Reward.1.Amount=0.01&Reward.1.CurrencyCode=USD&&AssignmentDurationInSeconds=180&Keywords=image%20inappropriate&QualificationRequirement.1.QualificationTypeId=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&QualificationRequirement.1.Comparator=EqualTo&QualificationRequirement.1.IntegerValue=10&QualificationRequirement.1.RequiredToPreview=true&AWSAccessKeyId=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&Timestamp=2012-11-29T07%3A04%3A15.867Z&Signature=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ&Service=AWSMechanicalTurkRequester&Operation=RegisterHITType&Version=2008-08-02

'QualificationRequirement' is correct. 'qualificationRequirement' will not work. So be careful in character capitalization.